# Error message in R after by or split file processing?

Tags: r

I run the following code in R:

```
library("AER")
data(CPS1985,package="AER")
by(CPS1985[c("wage","age","experience")],CPS1985["gender"],mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

But whenever I do I always get an error message as follows:

```
by(CPS1985[c("wage","age","experience")],CPS1985["gender"],mean,na.rm=TRUE)
gender: male
[1] NA
gender: female
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I have also checked before running the code that wage, age and experience are all numeric and gender is a factor variable. So I am little confused as to why I am getting this error message?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `colMeans`  with `by` when there is more than one `column`

```
by(CPS1985[, c("wage", "age", "experience")], CPS1985["gender"], 
                                            FUN=colMeans, na.rm=TRUE)
#gender: male
#      wage        age experience 
#  9.994913  35.979239  16.965398 
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#gender: female
#     wage        age experience 
#  7.878857  37.840816  18.832653
```

Or you could use `summarise_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
CPS1985 %>% 
        group_by(gender) %>% 
        summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), wage, age, experience)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

#   gender     wage      age experience
# 1   male 9.994913 35.97924   16.96540
# 2 female 7.878857 37.84082   18.83265
```

Answer (score 1):

A data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(CPS1985)  ## convert data to data table
CPS1985[, lapply(.SD, mean(na.rm=TRUE)), by=gender, .SDcols=c("wage","age","experience")]
   gender     wage      age experience
1: female 7.878857 37.84082   18.83265
2:   male 9.994913 35.97924   16.96540
```